# Is there an option to display timestamps in my local timezone?

Tags: support, feature-request, timezone

During a chat or asking a question we get a time (i.e. the time at which the event has happened or the time at which the user has asked the question) based on the GMT (I guess).

Could I possibly change the time to display the local standard time? If this is possible, then please tell me how. If not, then can't we have this feature?

Comment: No, such thing does not exist. If you really want, you'll have to write a userscript.

Comment: Update: [such script already exists](http://stackapps.com/questions/2528/display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time), feel free to install. Oops, just noticed http://userscripts.org is no more so... sorry.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no idea why, but http://userscripts.org:8080/ works

Comment: @Joe nice, looks like it's some server cache. Suggested a fix to the broken links, too bad so many free sites end up dead without any warning.

Comment: so can we have this feature built-in instead of any Add-on as @ShadowWizard has promptly said

Comment: @user285oo6 I doubt the team will do it, it was already suggested before on MSE and never got any official attention. So, don't expect it to happen.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I wanted it built-in because in some areas like a workplace the add-ons will be disabled permanently  thereby making it of no use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I guess chat is based on UTC like everything in The Stack Exchange Network.

There is no built-in similar feature to SE, but on StackApps there is a script, which should do that - https://stackapps.com/questions/2528/display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time - try to download and install it. That should help you.

I am oppose to make select-able timezones in TSE, cause UTC has been created to unify all times around the world.

Comment: Selectable *display*-tz are good user experience, though your argument is valid for *persistence*, which should always be in UTC, or at least Local+Offset.