# Consider the client's time zone when showing time under the questions

Tags: feature-request, timestamps, timezone

Let's explain an issue that I have:

I have asked a question two days ago (2022-01-23 13:00:11Z) and now (2021-01-25 08:04:00Z), when I open the question, I am seeing the following information:

- Asked yesterday
- Active yesterday
- Viewed 44 times

But it should show a date or *A day before yesterday* because 'yesterday' is not correct.

Here is my question's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70822294/use-generic-type-to-specify-exception-type).

In my time zone, (2022-01-23 13:00:11Z) is not yesterday. I will be so much better if you consider my time zone when showing the time under the questions (as I described above).

This is a question that explains my problem in more detail [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288916/wrong-display-of-a-questions-last-active-property).

Comment: At the very least related: [See time in a different timezone than UTC](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265296), [Is there an option to display timestamps in my local timezone?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261413)

Comment: And over on Uber Meta: [Make recent activity "today" etc. buttons based on user's time zone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1359) (2009, declined by Jeff Atwood), and a discussion from the same era: [Why are the time stamps in UTC instead of localized for the client?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2941)

Comment: Is your problem mainly that the wording is incorrect, or do you actually want the "today/yesterday/before-yesterday" categories? For me it's mostly relevant how long a question is up – the fix would be rather to have "today/a day ago/two days ago" in that case.

Comment: Just move to a country that has a timezone identical to UTC ;-). That's a) under your control and b) much more likely than any other solution to actually happen.

Comment: Related: *[Wrong time in Asked and Active part of question title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415546)*